# How can I apply a font type to everything using css

Tags: css

Basically, I need to adjust the font type everywhere it isn't specified.  How can I do that?  `table`, `div`, `span`, `p`, `input`, you name it.  Is there a way I can do them all with 1 CSS rule that I can add?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes** there is, use it on the body element and it will cascade down to all children unless you specify otherwise.

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
#tahoma {
    font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
```

**You can then override it**

```
<body>
  <div id="default">
    I will inherit the body font-family, in this case Arial because no other rule has been set!
  </div> 
  <div id="tahoma">
    <p>Me, <span>Me</span> and <strong>Me</strong> are using Tahoma because our parent #tahoma says so.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Damn you beat me by like 5 seconds ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is why it's called **Cascading** Style Sheets. Styles set at any level will "cascade" down. So if you set this styling on the `body` element, every other element in the `body` will take on the same styles.

```
body {
    font: ...;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's missing from the existing answers is the fact that the font family of some elements, like `input`, is unaffected by simply setting the font family for `body`, as suggested here.

The reason is that an element inside the body inherits the font family setting only if there is *no rule* that specifies this setting for this element. For elements like `input` (and also `pre`, `code`, etc.), there usually *are* rules that specify the font family: the basic styling rules defined by the browser.

To override the browser default, one needs to explicitly set the font family for these elements:

```
body, input, button, textarea {
    font-family: ...;
}
```

Note that `!important` should not be necessary to achieve this. Using `!important` is a sign that the stylesheets were not designed carefully enough.

Answer (score -3):

Use !important css property.

http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqimportn.htm

Like:

```
*{
YOUR_FONT_STYLE
}
```

Comment: But why use !important? it's a hack, and setting the font on the body will cascade down.

Comment: I thought OP needed to apply it to **everything**.

Comment: !important should only be used in scenarios where the order of your CSS definitions is crap, and you need rule x to override rule y.